# Tiempo exacto del push en Github

Tags: github, push

Es muy importante que pueda saber el horario exacto de cuando se hizo el push a un repositorio en GitHub. Solo logro ver el día. Estoy tomando un examen y el mismo tiene el tiempo de entrega a las 13 hs. y es muy importante que pueda saber exactamente esta información.

Answer (score 0):

No sé en `github` cómo ver la fecha y hora, pero, teniendo el valor `hash` del commit del que deseas obtener la fecha y hora, podrías escribir este comando de `git` que te devolverá la fecha y hora del mismo:

```bash
git show -s --format=%ci <commit>
```

El comando `show` muestra información del Objeto que quieras, en este caso el Objeto es el commit, cuya referencia es el `hash` del mismo.

El flag `-s` hace referencia al *subject* o asunto del commit

El flag `--format` con el valor `%ci` mostrará la fecha de realización del commit, incluyendo la hora, en formato [ISO 8601](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Puedes encontrar otras opciones en la [documentación](https://schacon.github.io/git/git-show) de `git show`.

Answer (score 0):

Cada commit lleva su estampa de tiempos, pero push no es un commit, es simplemente una transferencia de los commits pendientes. Por tanto push no lleva estampa de tiempo.

Probablemente github sí que tenga un log de cuándo se recibe el push, pero hasta donde yo sé no es información visible para el usuario. Todo lo que puedes obtener es la fecha y hora de cada commit (y por tanto del más reciente) pero no de cuándo se recibieron esos commits via push.

En el lado cliente es posible configurar git para que guarde un log de cuándo accede a los remotos, pero al ser información local no valdría como "prueba" para un examinador, me temo.

Ahora bien, si lo que buscas es ver la fecha y hora exacta del commit más reciente (y no de cuándo se recibió por push) esa información sí que está en el repositorio github. Mira [aqui](https://medium.com/@brett.stone/how-to-find-the-exact-time-of-a-github-commit-github-com-or-github-desktop-58db3ffef812) por ejemplo para los detalles

Básicamente, dejando el ratón sobre el texto "7 days ago" o lo que sea del commit, un tooltip te mostrará la hora exacta.